# Is it possible to mount the Samsung S27E370 monitor on a VESA arm?

Tags: monitors, monitor-stand

It seems like S27E370 does not have a VESA mount that is compatible with most of the monitor arms on the market. I searched for adapters, but it's not even clear how I'd go about detaching the default stand.

What would be the best about mounting S27E370 on a VESA monitor arm?

Other notes:

- https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/led/ls27e370ds-za-ls27e370ds-za/
- Sometimes this model is identified with LS27E370DS
- The user manual provides dimensions and weight for that monitor without a stand, which suggests that the stand can be detached. Refer to https://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201509/20150918095315520/BN46-00487A-Eng.pdf.

Comment: I do see the monitor stand has a plastic cover above. So probably you can take that off and unscrew the stand. However this seems like a monitor to use as is, because of the wireless charging thing in the stand. Why not buy another with VESA mount. For the adapter you can use something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Universal-Adapter-Non-VESA-Monitor-Screens/dp/B088CWY5Q3).

Comment: @ServiceDeskBunny Buying another monitor is always an option :) I was wondering if there is some standard way people approach Samsung monitors, as they all seem to be slightly different and require different adapters.

The universal VESA adapter looks very interesting. Sure it won't look pretty with the original stand still attached to the monitor, but it is a very viable option. Thank you! I'm new to this SE, but your comment feels like a very good answer on its own. I'd be happy to accept it and reward you with points :).